# Value not correctly transferred by href

Tags: php, href

I make a select from a table, this is fine and I display the result like this:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name = $row["rcp_name"];
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>"; echo $name; echo "</td>";              
    echo "<td>"; echo $row["enter_dte"]; echo "</td>";
    echo  "<td>"; echo "<a href='file2.php?nme=$name'>Edit</a>";  echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; }
```

this gives below result:

- **Name   Enter date**
  Adam   2017-01-26  Edit
  Benny  2017-01-26  Edit
  Carl   2017-01-27  Edit
  David  2017-01-27  Edit

However, when I click on edit for e.g. Benny this value is not transferred to file2.php. Value Carl is transferred. If I click on Carl then David is transferred. I have tried without tables and just used linebreakes but with the same result. If I print all just as a string then it works but this is of course not an option. Can anyone figure out what I do wrong? Or is there a better way to achive this. Thanks for any suggestions.

In target script I identify the value with 
echo $_GET['nme'];

Comment: Try `var_dump($_GET);` in your target script to see if anything is being sent.

Comment: Try this mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)

Comment: @Shubhranshu will you explain how this will help, he is already displaying the data so getting from DB is not an issue here.

Comment: It will ensure that he gets the data with field name not as numeric field.

Comment: @Shubhranshu  mysqli_fetch_array gives data in both format with numeric as well as columns as keys if no flag specified. but using flag is good or he can use fetch_assoc.

Comment: Step one: Go check what the actual links look like in the HTML output.

Comment: I tried to change my db calls but it didn't help. Then I found that I for other purposes in my site have this defined in my CSS file:a:link, a:visited 
   {
   width: 100px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 37px;
   margin-top: 15px;
   text-decoration: none;
   }  The padding and the margin-top caused my problem. After I removed this everything worked fine. Many thanks for your interest and suggestions.